# Installing Ubuntu on Dell inspiron 13 7000

Tags: system-installation

I recently got a dell inspiron 13 7000 and will like to disable the windows completely and install ubuntu. Is it possible, if yes how can I go about it? By the OS is windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you completely want to remove windows you can go by this on Ubuntu Installation.

However, I recommend to do this first.

Assuming you use UEFI, Boot into BIOS then disable secure boot and fast startup
this will eliminate most problems encountered upon post-installation of Ubuntu as well as hardware detection.

Use Rufus to for Ubuntu ISO set the scheme to GPT for UEFI then start burning it to your pen drive then boot into it.

After that follow this link with detailed instructions as well as screenshots.

[Guide To Ubuntu Installation](https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-17-10-installation-guide-screenshots/)

Now, Since you are a beginner user you can skip following the disk guide on that link and just use

> Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu

Normally you would want this for the default partition of linux

> WARNING
>   "This will certainly overwrite your Windows Partition"

Hope This Helps.

Comment: Dell heavily locks down their Windows computers. Saying "boot into BIOS" doesn't help because by default, Dell doesn't let you do that.